# Jensen–Shannon divergence analysis of numbers

Tags: distance, probability, distribution, entropy, uncertainty

The Jensen–Shannon divergence is a method of measuring the similarity between two probability distributions and it is bounded by 1 ( 0 <= JSD(p,q) <= 1). I have applied the python code of Jensen–Shannon divergence and I want to analyze my results. I can't understand what the resulted numbers mean. What is the meaning of JSD(p,q)=1 or JSD(p,q)=0 ?

Comment: What was you expecting in the first place? Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're calculating Jensen-Shannon distance, `JSD(p,q) = 0` says the two distributions are similar/equal. If it's `1` they're very different.